# Can't map fetched data in react js (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'))

Tags: reactjs, axios, spotify, map-function

I have fetched data from Spotify API and it displays in console but when I try to return data inpage it says map is not defined I use `useState([])` and pass it to array if I am saying it right way:

```
const [track, setTrack] = useState([])
const getRecommendation = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const {data} = await axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    params: {
      limit: '10',
      seed_artists: '4NHQUGzhtTLFvgF5SZesLK',
      seed_genres: 'rock,pop,metal',
      seed_tracks: '0c6xIDDpzE81m2q797ordA'
    }
  })
  setTrack(data.tracks.item)
  console.log(data);
  
}
const renderTracks = () => {
  return track.map(tracks => {
    return (
       <h1 className='track-name'>
       {tracks.name}
       </h1>
      )
  }) 
}
```

Here in console:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: What is getRecommendation() for? Can't see anything calling it, it does nothing. Your tracks won't be there.

Comment: getRecommendation is called onClick and shows that console data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:

```
console.log(data);
```

The `data` object has a property called `tracks` which is an array.  Which means this:

```
setTrack(data.tracks.item);
```

Is setting the state to `undefined`, because there is no `.item` property on an array.

This implies that you're expecting to iterate over an array:

```
return track.map(tracks => {
```

So set the state to the array, not some property you expect to be on the array:

```
setTrack(data.tracks);
```

---

As an aside, the plurality in your names is *backwards*.  This is going to cause confusion for you (if it hasn't already).  Consider the semantics of this:

```
return track.map(tracks => {
```

In this line of code, `track` is an array and `tracks` is a single object.  That's not how plurality works.  Rename your variables to accurately reflect what they contain:

```
const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([]);
```

and:

```
setTracks(data.tracks);
```

and:

```
return tracks.map(track => {
```

This could very well be what caused your problem in the first place, since `setTrack` implies that it's expecting a *single object* and `data.tracks` is an *array*.

Keep your variable names consistent and meaningful and your code will be much easier to read and understand.